# python import error from setup.py if dependencies are not installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, setup.py

In one my python package in `setup.py` is imported module `__about__.py` located inside package (where are stored all metadata and want to share it between pakcage and setup).

`setup.py` also installing other dependent third-party library for my package.

Also inside package in module `__init__.py` are imported other modules like (`from mypackage.mymodule import MyClass`) to keep simple usage (because is easier to write `import mypackage` and then `a = mypackage.MyClass()`).

The problem is if `setup.py` importing `__about__.py` then is also executed `__init__.py` from package and everything deeper and this generate import error during install, because there is still not installed my dependent library.

The structure is:

```
setup.py
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    __about__.py
    mymodule.py
```

I would like to keep same usage and keep structure but solve the import problem during setup if the dependent module was not installed before. probably best way will be to import `mypackage.__about__` without executing `__init__.py`, but how?

Or any other advice is welcome.

The package is python3 only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found solution by replacing `import mypackage.__about__` in `setup.py` with exec:

```
_ABOUT = {}
exec(open('mypackage/__about__.py').read(), _ABOUT)

setuptools.setup(
    name=_ABOUT['NAME'],
    version=_ABOUT['VERSION'],
    ...
```

File `__about__.py` contains:

```
NAME = 'mypackage'
VERSION = 'v1.0.0'
...
```

This solution is working well. Only one minor issue is PEP warning [W0122](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0122)